# Como extraigo el valor de getItemCount() de un recyclerview

Tags: android, recyclerview

Como puedo mostrar en un textview el valor del metodo `getItemCount()`

Me explico tengo un recyclerview el cual muestra fotografias que tomo en este caso lo que quiero es que cuando yo tome en el textview me muestre `1/13` el valor 13 esta por default el unico que cambiaria seria el primero en este caso el 1 ya que es el valor extraido del metodo ItemCount

```
@Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return lista.size();
    }
```

Actualmente lo mando a llamar de la siguiente manera pero solo se queda mi textview como `0/13`

```
etimg = view.findViewById(R.id.tvimg);
etimg.setText(adapter.getItemCount() + "/13");
```

Pero si coloco el mismo codigo en la clase adapter y lo mando a llamar en un textview dentro del recycler ahi si me extre el valor pero cuando lo llamo fuera del recycler solo se queda en 0 anexo imagen.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

GalleryFragment.java

```
public class GalleryFragment extends Fragment {

    FragmentGalleryBinding binding;
    RecyclerView listaFotos;
    private List<Bitmap> lista;
    FotoAdapter adapter = new FotoAdapter(lista, getContext());
    int count = adapter.getItemCount();
    Usuario usuario;

    TextView etTipo,etCaja,etdestino,etimg;
    Button btnAddImg;



    private List<Bitmap> fotos =  new ArrayList<>();

    public GalleryFragment() {
    }

        public void setDatos (Usuario datos){
        this.usuario = datos;
    }

    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        GalleryViewModel galleryViewModel =
                new ViewModelProvider(this).get(GalleryViewModel.class);

        binding = FragmentGalleryBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);
        View root = binding.getRoot();

        listaFotos=binding.listaFotos;
        adapter=new FotoAdapter(fotos, getContext());
        listaFotos.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(getContext(), 4));
        listaFotos.setAdapter(adapter);

        FloatingActionButton btn=binding.fotografiar;
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                hacerFoto();
            }
        });

        return root;
    }

    private File archivo;
    private void hacerFoto() {
        try {
            Intent i =  new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

            archivo = crearFichero();
            Uri foto = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getContext(), "com.example.rampasimage.fileprovider", archivo);
            i.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, foto);

            startActivityForResult(i, 1);
        }catch (IOException e){
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Error:" + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        if (requestCode==1){
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){

                Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(archivo.getAbsolutePath());
                fotos.add(image);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

        }else {

        }

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    private File crearFichero() throws IOException {
        String pre="foto_";
        File directorio=getContext().getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        File img = File.createTempFile(pre + UUID.randomUUID().toString(),".jpg", directorio);
        return img;
    }

    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        etTipo = view.findViewById(R.id.tvtipo);
        etCaja = view.findViewById(R.id.tvtrailer);
        etdestino = view.findViewById(R.id.tvdest);
        btnAddImg = view.findViewById(R.id.addImg);
        etimg = view.findViewById(R.id.tvimg);


        etTipo.setText("" + usuario.getTipo());
        etCaja.setText(usuario.getCaja());
        etdestino.setText(usuario.getDestino());
        etimg.setText(count + "/13");

    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        binding = null;
    }
}
```

FotoAdapter.java

```
public class FotoAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<FotoAdapter.ViewHolder>{

    public List<Bitmap> lista;
    Context context;


    public FotoAdapter(List<Bitmap> lista, Context context) {
        this.lista = lista;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_foto,parent,false);
        return new ViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Bitmap bit=lista.get(position);
        holder.image.setImageBitmap(bit);
        holder.txcou.setText(lista.size() + "/13");

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return lista.size();
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        private ImageView image;

        Button add;

        TextView txcou;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            image=itemView.findViewById(R.id.foto);
            txcou=itemView.findViewById(R.id.size);
            add=itemView.findViewById(R.id.addImg);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No termino de entender tu consulta, puesto que al lado de Destino dice 0997 y al lado 0/13 pero en la esquina superior izquierda de las fotos que tomaste dice: 2/13

Comment: Si mira el que esta en el lado izquierdo de las fotos fue una prueba para ver si la manera de extraer el valor era correcta y si funciono pero solo dentro del recyclerview me muestre el valor de `lista.size()` - pero yo requiero ese valor en el que esta a lado de destino que dice `0997`. esto debido a que si lo extraego en el recycler me lo repite como se puede apreciar en la imagen.

Comment: @AlbertoCruz No uses adapter.getItemCount(), obten la medida de la lista con lista.size() y usa ese valor, revisa mi respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

**El valor de `getItemCount()` lo puedes obtener desde otra clase, pero en este caso es necesario que previamente se halla realizado la inicialización del `Adapter`**.

```
FotoAdapter adpater = new FotoAdapter(lista, context);
int count = adapter.getItemCount();
```

Comment: Ya lo hice como dijiste y lo mande a llamar a mi clase GalleryFragment fuera del adapter y aun asi no logro obtener el valor me continua apareciendo como `0/13` mientras que en el recycler me muestra repetido el textview con el valor del `lista.size()` y eso no es lo que quiero. Lo que quiero es obtener el valor fuera del recycler

Comment: ¿Estás intentando llamar getItemCount() desde otra clase afuera del Adapter?

Comment: Revisa la actualización de mi respuesta.

Comment: Debo inicializar el adapter en la clase donde voy a extraer el vlaor o en el adapter

Comment: En la clase donde vas a extraer el valor.

Comment: Me da el siguiente error `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int java.util.List.size()' on a null object reference`, ya actualice mi pregunta y anexe mi codigo adapter y la clase `Gallery`

Comment: Es que estás enviando como valor de "lista" un null al inicializar : FotoAdapter adpater = new FotoAdapter(lista, context);

Comment: Como puedo corregir entonces esto o que me recomiendas

Comment: Inicialize el valor como me dijiste

Comment: `private List<Bitmap> lista = new ArrayList<>();
    FotoAdapter adapter = new FotoAdapter(lista, getContext());
    int count = adapter.lista.size();`

Comment: `etimg.setText(count + "/13");`

Comment: Pero continua dandome `0`

Comment: Probe con `int count = adapter.lista.size();` y con `int count = adapter.getItemCount();` y con ambos me continua dando `0`

Comment: Ok, entonces en la clase donde estas tu lista tiene 0 elementos, revisa que obtienes de esta forma: int count = lista.size();

Comment: Es que la lista si resive valores por que son fotogragfias y el valor si me lo devuelve en el text view dentro del recyclerview pero fuera no tal y como esta la imagen de la pregunta

Answer (score 0):

Hola creo que deberia agregar la actualizacion de tu textview al tomar una nueva foto

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
if (requestCode==1){
if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){

```
            Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(archivo.getAbsolutePath());
            fotos.add(image);
            etimg.setText(fotos.size) + "/13");
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

    }else {

    }

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```